# reading .dv files using opencv, can't find dv header error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-processing

Trying to read a '.dv' video file format from a microscopy hardware (and I can not change the hardware and origin of the files).
trying to use the opencv.VideoCapture('file_location.dv') function brings up an error:

> OSError: Could not load meta information
> === stderr ===
>
> ffmpeg version 4.1-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c)
> 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers   built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0
> (clang-1000.11.45.5)   configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang
> --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay   libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100   libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100   libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100   libavdevice    58.  5.100 /
> 58.  5.100   libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101   libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100   libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100   libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100 [dv @ 0x7fa84a000000] Format dv
> detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible! [dv @
> 0x7fa84a000000] Cannot find DV header.
> /Users/yishaiazabary/PycharmProjects/platelets/t2.dv: Operation not
> permitted

I tried to convert to different file formats but I'm losing way to much information.
I also tried using the following libraries as well:
Scikit-image
imageio
av
moviepy

> import cv2
>
> cap = cv2.VideoCapture('t2.dv')

I figured it might be related to the FFmpeg installation, but I couldn't find any solution regarding that.

I expect that the cap object will contain a Numpy ndarray with all RGB values of each pixel in a time series based on frames structure.

I'm also open to any other python library/package that will allow me to overcome the issue and retrieve an numpy ndarray.